# Cannot Construct The infinite type c = [c]

Tags: haskell, types, infinite

Okay so I am relatively new to programming in Haskell, and when working on a function to preorder return data from a tree, I came across this error.

Code:

```
preorder  ::(Show a, Show b) => (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c]
preorder x y (Leaf n) = x n
preorder x y (Branch b ltree rtree) = (y b) ++ (preorder x y ltree) ++ (preorder x y rtree)
```

Line 17:

```
preorder x y (Leaf n) = x n
```

Error Message:

```
A3.hs:17:0:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: c = [c]
    When generalising the type(s) for `preorder'
```

I am unaware if this may look weird to people, but the parameters given for this code were for this function to take in 2 other functions that convert the elements of the tree to a usable type. The first function is to take in a leaf of the tree and covert it, while the second function is to take in a branch and convert it and then to construct a list. This is the first attempt that came to mind to solve this.

Comment: The way you debug this type of thing in general is with typed holes - you know the result must involve `x` and `n` somehow, so you write what you have written, but the compiler tells you you are wrong. So then you write `preorder x y (Leaf n) = _helpMe (x n)` and it spits out `Found hole \`_helpMe' with type: c -> [c]`. Now there are still many functions of type `c -> [c]` ... but `(:[])` is certainly an obvious choice here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the declared type of `preorder`, `x :: a -> c` in your line 17. That means `x n :: c`. However, the return value of `preorder` is declared to be `[c]`. which means `x n :: [c]`. Line 17 should read

```
preorder x y (Leaf n) = [x n]
```

That is, the return value for a leaf must be a singleton list which can be concatenated to the other values. For the same reason, line 18 will need to read

```
preorder x y (Branch b ltree rtree) = [(y b)] ++ (preorder x y ltree) ++ (preorder x y rtree)
```

since `y :: b -> c` implies that `(y b) :: c`, not `[c]` that will be needed for the `++` operator.